# Web Carousel Control Prev and Next dissapeared

Tags: html, carousel

So on the picture below I have made a carousel successfully but the problem is that the next button is on the white side of the page. I tried to enlarge the size of the carousel but it ends up going below the container of the category.

[image]

```css
//not a css but the style section i just separated it.

 <style type="text/css">
    #carouselExampleControls .list-group {
      position:middle;
      top:0;
      right:5px;
    }
    #carouselExampleControls.list-group-item {
      border-radius:0px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #carouselExampleControls.list-group .active {
      background-color:#eee;  
    }
      @media (min-width: 802px) { 
      #carouselExampleControls {padding-right:34.3333%;}
      #carouselExampleControls .carousel-controls {}  
 
    }


    .carousel-control.left {
      margin-left: -25px;
    }

    .carousel-control.right {
      margin-right: -25px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 802px) { 
      .carousel-caption p,
      #carouselExampleControls .list-group {} 
    }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    /* Style the header */
    .header {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Style the top navigation bar */
    .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    /* Style the topnav links */
    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Change color on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    /* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
    .column {
        float: auto;
        padding: 0px;
       
    }

    /* Left and right column */
    .column.side {
        width: 20%;
        padding-left: 30px;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    /* Middle column */
    .column.middle {
        width: 100%;
       padding-left: 10px;

    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    /* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 100%) {
        .column.side, .column.middle {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    </style>
```

```html
   <br>
      <div class="row" style="padding-left: 300px;">
      <div class="column side" >
        <h2>Category</h2>
        <ul>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="http://demo.mysterythemes.com/easy-store/product-category/winter-collection/" >Winter Collection</a>
        </li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-18"><a href="http://demo.mysterythemes.com/easy-store/product-category/women-collection/" >Women Collection</a>
        </li>
        </ul>     
      </div>

      <div class="column middle" style="width: 1100px">
         <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/1img.jpg" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/2img.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/3img.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So when I tried to enlarge the photo using the
`<div class="column middle" style="width: 1200px">`
the result would become like this.

[image]

So the result that I wanted was just to fix the carousel to be in lined with the margin that has set and to show the next button ">". How can I achieve this? Help me senpais.

Answer (score 0):

You could try absolutely positioning your anchor links so

```
.column a{
     position:absolute;
     right: 0;
     top:100;
 }
```

or to be a bit more specific you could target nth-child(1) and nth-child(2)

so:

```
.column a{
    position:absolute;
    top:100;
}
.column a:nth-child(1){
    left:0;
}

.column a:nth-child(2){
    right:0;
}
```

Then all you need to do is adjust to suit what you need. Hope this helps.